# How to update many to many tables using Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework.

I have 3 tables: `Employees`, `Activity`, `EmployeeActivity` { EmployeeId, ActivityId }.

When user wants to update data he changes `EmployeeId` from dropdownlist and `ActivityId` from dropdownlist of that...

`EmployeeActivity` does not exist in my model there is navigation property of that.

Now I want to know how can i found related row and update that?

Suppose the there is value `(1, 2)` in `EmployeeActivity` and I want to edit that to `(3, 4)`.

How can I find the `(1, 2)` to be changed? There are no other rows in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like you to a suggestion that take an extra field in your ViewModel, having field like below

```
OldEmployeeId
EmployeeId
OldActivityId
ActivityId

**Note:** set the same value in identical fields like EmployeeId & OldEmployeeId same to ActivityId and OldActivityId. so when you saving/updating records you have a reference of previously selected value in OldEmployeeId & OldActivityId so it will help you to identify the record and update the value.
```

Another option is that if you don't want to go for the above solution then take an extra field in the database table ID as a primary key so it will store reference where you need to update.